# make scroll only after certain width. instead of shrinking content

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am developing a site, I want the site to be scrollable after a certain width reduction, instead of shrinking the contents. how can I achieve this?

Comment: share your code so that people can help you where you are struck

Comment: Technically, you can acheive that by checking clientWidth in javascript/jQuery, and apply the desired effect/scroll/overflow based on the returned value.

Comment: actually, I am not stuck. I came across this question.@tanmay. I want the browser not to shrink my content, instead what I want is it should be scrollable
On browser resize the content should be hidden not shrunk

Comment: Please show your work so far. We can't help you if you don't.

Comment: Okay @Soviut, You want my CSS or entire CSS, HTML

Comment: @SibiRaj - To prevent the browser from scaling your content you need to specify a scale factor in your document head, as shown in my answer below.

Comment: thanks @allnodcoms.

Comment: @SibiRaj no, not all your CSS or HTML, just the minimum amount in order to demonstrate the problem you're having.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to prevent the site from scaling you need to specify the meta tag 'viewport' in your document's head.

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no, maximum-scale=1.0"/>
```

This should automatically add scrolling, but if not you will need to specifically add it with a `@media` query in your CSS.

Answer (score 0):

try css `@media` like

```
/* Viewport width at least */
@media (min-width: 50px) {
  your style staff
}
```

Comment: I am not into responsiveness, I want to cut out the responsiveness

Comment: set `overflow: scroll;` on contents parent div